# Add strings to string array

Tags: c#

```
class Myclass
{
    static string[] user_Name = { "admin", "user1", "user2" };
    static string[] user_Password ={ "admin", "123", "789" };

    public static void Check_Method(string u_name, string u_password)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < user_Name.Length; i++)
        {
            if (u_name == user_Name[i] && u_password == user_Password[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login successful");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == (user_Name.Length - 1))
                    MessageBox.Show("Badshow");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void add_user(string name, string password)
    {
        i=user_Name.Length;
        user_Name[i]=name;
        user_Password[i]=password;
        //here i want to add another user but im unable to find the way
    }
}
```

But it gives an error that it is outside the boundary of an array.

What could be the most convenient way to perform this action?

Comment: The reason for the array out of bounds error is that you are using the length of the user name as the index into your user_Name array.  This isn't really the meat of the question but I thought you should know.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use arrays if you need variable sized storage.

Use `List<string>` instead - it allows you to `Add` items.

---

In your case, your choice of two arrays is questionable, as each user has a corresponding password - always. This suggests that you should have a custom class to hold a user/password pair.

With such a class (say `User`), you would hold a `List<User>` and simplify your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `List<>`.

```
class Myclass
{
    static List<string> user_Name = new List<string>{ "admin", "user1", "user2" };
    static List<string> user_Password = new List<string>{ "admin", "123", "789" };

    public static void Check_Method(string u_name, string u_password)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < user_Name.Length; i++)
        {
            if (u_name == user_Name[i] && u_password == user_Password[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login successful");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == (user_Name.Length - 1))
                    MessageBox.Show("Badshow");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void add_user(string name, string password)
    {
        user_Name.Add(name);
        user_Password.Add(password);
    }
}
```

Here's a refactored version:

Users are contained in a user class.

They are `IEquatable<>` which compares their username/passwords (you might want to consider looking into a `Guid` to keep them unique).

Easily add/remove users.

```
public class User : IEquatable<User>
{
    public User(string name, string password)
    {
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(User other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;

        return other.Name == Name && other.Password == Password;
    }
}

public class AuthenticationManager
{
    private List<User> LoggedInUsers = new List<User>
    { new User("Admin", "admin"), new User ("user1", "123"), new User ("user2", "789") };

    public bool Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = new User(userName, password);

        //if the user is in the list it will return false otherwise true.
        return !LoggedInUsers.Any(u => user.Equals(user)); 
    }

    public void Login(string name, string password)
    {
        LoggedInUsers.Add(new User(name, password));
    }

    public void Logout(string name, string password)
    {
        LoggedInUsers.Remove(new User(name, password));
    }
}
```

Comment: This would get out of hand pretty quickly.  I'd always recommend that newcomers get to grips with OOP concepts ASAP.

Comment: o great bro... thix ix also a better way

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think you might be thinking about this the wrong way.  The way in which you're using arrays is screaming out for an object.

I would made User an object like so

```
public class User 
{
  public string UserName { get; set;}
  public string Password { get; set;}
}
```

I would then maintain a list of Users instead.  That way you won't need to maintain array indexes and you can easily add new users into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use and `List` and apply a DTO instead of multiples `string[]` ?

Try something like this:

1) Create a DTO for your Users:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

2) Use and `List<DTO>`

```
class Myclass
{
    static List<UserDTO> users = new List<UserDTO>()
    {
        new UserDTO() { UserName= "admin", Password = "admin" } ,
        new UserDTO() { UserName= "user1", Password = "123" } ,
        new UserDTO() { UserName= "user2", Password = "789" } ,
    }

    public static void Check_Method(string u_name, string u_password)
    {
        if (users.Exists(x => x.UserName == u_name && x.Password == u_password)
        {
               MessageBox.Show("login successful");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Badshow");
        }
    }
    public static void add_user(string name, string password)
    {
        users.Add(new UserDTO() { UserName= name, Password = password });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `List<string>` class instead of `string[]`

and add items to array using `object.Add()` method